# Cateye HR-10 heart rate monitor not recording

Tags: bike-computer

I bought a Cateye heart monitor HR-10 to record my heart rate on the Cateye digital cc-rd420dw, but my heart rate is not being recorded on the Cateye digital. I have put a new battery into the heart rate monitor, placed water on the sensor pads and tried rubbing them with my thumbs to test if it would record my heart rate but it is not recording. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Have you paired the sensor with the cycle computer? Is there an app you can put on your phone to test pairing with that? When you say "not recording", do you mean that you're getting no heart-rate information at all, or just that it's not being stored with the rest of your ride? (Sorry to only offer more questions. I'm not familiar with the Cateye systems so I don't have any answers, but I think we'll need a bit more information before anyone can help.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pair the strap with the computer (otherwise everyone's cateye HR monitors would interfere with each other).

There are instructions for pairing on page 7 of the manual.  It is not a very intuitive process.

1. Press the menu button on the back of the computer to get to the settings
2. Press mode on the computer to get to the ID synch page
3. Press and hold the mode button until sp1 is shown
4. Press the mode button to cycle to the HR page
5. Press the Reset button on the back of the HR monitor
6. When the HR is found, press the menu button on the back of the computer

[Cateye RD420DW manual](https://www.cateye.com/intl/support/manual/data/doc/CC-RD420DW_HP_ENG_v3.pdf)